# Display operatingsystem property in a message box

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble getting the operatingsystem property for computers in Active Directory(AD).  Here is the code I am having trouble with and the function that gets the property from AD.  The hostname works perfectly but the OS_Name displays a blank message box.

Alternatively, I would also like help formatting the filter to make things easier down the road.  My goal is to check the operating system and only process the Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 7 Enterprise operating systems but I can't even display the operating system in a message box.  Please help.

```
    Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = New 
    DirectoryEntry("GC://my.work.com/DC=AB27,DC=my,DC=work,DC=com")
    Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
        mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)")
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dNSHostName")
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem")
        Dim ds As SearchResult
        For Each ds In mySearcher.FindAll()
            Dim OS_Name As String = GetProperty(ds, "operatingSystem")
            Dim hostName As String = GetProperty(ds, "dNSHostName")
            MessageBox.Show(hostName)
            MessageBox.Show(OS_Name)
        Next
    Function GetProperty(ByVal searchResult As SearchResult, ByVal 
    PropertyName As String)
    If searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName) Then
        Return searchResult.Properties(PropertyName)(0).ToString()
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

I expect the message for the operating system to display the operating system property.  Instead it displays a blank message box.

When I use debug.writeline instead of a message box it leaves a blank line between each hostname as if it reads the OS but just adds a line to hold the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is in your DirectoryEntry nor if why you have structured your filter is causing a problem but the following shows me my hostname and operating system...

```
        Dim enTry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry
        Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(enTry)
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dNSHostName")
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem")
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystemVersion")
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(operatingSystem=*server*))"


        Dim resEnt As SearchResult
        For Each resEnt In mySearcher.FindAll()
            Dim OS_Name As String
            Dim hostName As String
            hostName = GetProperty(resEnt, "dNSHostName")
            OS_Name = GetProperty(resEnt, "operatingSystem")

        Next
```